# Splash screen should be initialized before rendering home screen

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

...
I am trying to remove Drawer Navigation and use bottom navigation instead, but I am not able to display the splash screen and then the home screen. Please help me as I am totally new to React Native
...

...
navigation code
...

```
import React from "react";
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer, createBottomTabNavigator } from "react-navigation";
import DoctorHome from "../containers/Home/DoctorHome/DoctorHome";
import Appointments from "../containers/DoctorFlow/Appointments/Appointments";
import EditProfile from "../containers/DoctorFlow/EditProfile/EditProfile";
import ViewClinic from "../containers/DoctorFlow/ViewClinic/ViewClinic";
import AddClinic from "../containers/DoctorFlow/AddClinic/AddClinic";
import Profile from "../containers/DoctorFlow/Profile/Profile";
import Proffession from "../containers/DoctorFlow/Profile/Proffession";
import {
  View,
  Image,
  Touchable,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  Platform
} from "react-native";
  const HomeStack = createStackNavigator ({
    Home: DoctorHome,
    Appointments: Appointments,
    EditProfile: EditProfile
  });
  const ClinicStack = createStackNavigator ({
    Clinic: ViewClinic,
    AddClinic: AddClinic
  });
  const ProfileStack = createStackNavigator ({
    Profile: Profile,
    EditProfile: EditProfile,
    Proffession: Proffession
  });

  const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: HomeStack,
    Clinic: ClinicStack,
    Profile: ProfileStack
});
export const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

...
splash screen code
...

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { AsyncStorage, Image, StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TimerMixin from "react-timer-mixin";
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from "react-navigation";
class Splash extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      user: null
    };
  }
  componentWillMount() {}

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUser();
    TimerMixin.setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.state.user) {
        console.log(this.state.user.user.userType);
        if (this.state.user.user.userType == "DOCTOR") {
          if (this.state.user.user.isProfileCompleted == false) {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(
              StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [
                  NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "EditDoctorProfile" })
                ]
              })
            );
          } else {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(
              StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                actions: [
                  NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "DoctorHomeMenu" })
                ]
              })
            );
          }
        }
      } else {
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(
          StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Login" })]
          })
        );
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

  async getUser() {
    await AsyncStorage.getItem("user").then(user =>
      this.setState({ user: JSON.parse(user) })
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          justifyContent: "center",
          alignItems: "center",
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: "#fff"
        }}
      >
        <Image
          style={{ width: 200, height: 40 }}
          source={require("../Images/logo/logo.png")}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF",
    padding: 16
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 10
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: "center",
    color: "#333333",
    marginBottom: 5
  }
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  Login: () =>
    dispatch(
      NavigationActions.navigate({
        routeName: "Login"
      })
    )
});

export default connect(
  null,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Splash);
```

...
App.js (entry point)
...

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { AppNavigator } from "../Navigation/RootNavigation";
import configureStore from "../store/ConfigureStore";
import color from "../ui/color";
const store = configureStore();
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: color.primary
        }}
      >
        <StatusBar
          backgroundColor={"#000"}
          barStyle="light-content"
          hidden={false}
        />
        <Provider store={store}>
          <AppNavigator />
        </Provider>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

...
I want to display the logo first, and then I want a login/signup screen. Once the user logs in, he can access Home and inner screens.
But right now, I am directly getting Home screen as my opening screen. Please help me resolve this issue.
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably want to make the login stack the default route:

```
const MainNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: HomeStack,
    Clinic: ClinicStack,
    Profile: ProfileStack,
    Login: LoginStack
}, {initialRouteName: 'Login'});
```

You probably also want to add the splash screen make it the default route

```
 const LoginStack = createStackNavigator ({
    Login: Login,
    SignUp: SignUp,
    Splash: Splash
  }, {initialRouteName: 'Splash')
```

Comment: can you take a look at my code now? I actually do not want Login stack in my bottom tab navigator. is there any way to pass splash screen and render login and homepage conditionally?

Comment: You would probably use a switch navigator with both the login and home page stacks. And have it so when it goes to the login page, it checks if it should go to the home page. Otherwise, if I understand what you're asking for exactly, the way you would do it is to have an intermediary page that decides which stack to go to, but in essence this achieves that same thing with an extra superfluous page.